# What gui? Creating an order: many images, many print sizes

Tags: user-interface, user-experience

I have an app where users select images they wish to print, the print sizes they wish for each image, and a quantity for each image/print size pair.

I'm wondering what sort of GUI I can use to do this well. I do have to allow for 'batch adds' - i.e. clients are often professional photographers and may print a whole lot of images at several sizes, so I don't want to create a flow where they have to select a single image and go from there.

Currently, I allow selection of images and print sizes independently, with a qty field and an 'add' button. This works well for adding but I need a whole other UI to edit/remove items, and it doesn't represent the order state well.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, what about something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [fullahead.org](http://fullahead.org/work/stackoverflow/gui-print-ordering.png))</sub>

Initially all image thumbnails would have the blue Order Prints link.  On click it would create a Size dropdown and Quantity text field.

Once the user entered in both fields, a red "X" would appear beside it, allowing them to delete that specific order.

The user would also be able to keep clicking Order Prints on a single thumbnail to add multiple size/quantity orders for a single image.

As a nice usability feature, you could add a subtle selected indicator to thumbnails that have a print request on them.  This would let your users quickly see what images they have pending print orders on.

Comment: That looks nice, but doesn't address the 'batch' requirement - i.e. a pro photographer trying to order a single 8x10 print for 300 images would go nuts.

Comment: It might work well if I allow them to create image groups via multi-select/add group, then treat the group and single images together in the same way you have above. Getting complicated, but perhaps necessary. Thought provoking stuff - thanks.

Comment: That would definitely work well for the batch requirement.  Multi select images with check boxes or some other mechanism and then represent the group as a stack of photos, whereas single photos would just be their thumbnail